# How to reduce the vertical bounding box of a font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, font-design

I just extracted Twitter's iconography glyph font (before the new redesign) to also keep it in history (because I also much love it than the new one imho) and also study and use it on my Twitter UX concepts (the copyright is all on Twitter, just using it for my personal uses only), It's called Rosetta, but when you convert that WOFF font to OTF or TTF from any converters online, it shows a big vertical bounding box below, which makes picking glyphs on Photoshops difficult as they're cropped, like this:

[image]

How could I modify it using a 3rd party font maker tool like FontForge to remove that bounding box below so it will show correctly?

Comment: What converters were you using?

Comment: I'm using this online tool https://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-otf

Answer (score 1):

Font Forge can open .woff files and can do mass transformation of the glyphs, e.g., scaling, moving, etc.

If you are picking directly the image of the glyphs form screen grabs, FF can also show the glyphs in 128px size, and adjust the view to the bounding box or to the whole glyph.

Comment: Can you tell me it step by steps. Tbh I'm really new to Font Forge so I don't really know what I'm doing

Comment: Sure! I hope you don't have trouble installing FontForge. Using the usual commands to open the WOFF (File > Open) you will immediately see the font's glyph collection.

Comment: In the View menu you can un/select "Fit to font bounding box" to adjust the font view, and also the size of the glyphs preview.
When you select a glyph (use SHIFT to select many), you can use Element > Transformations > Transform to Move, Scale, Rotate, etc. the glyphs. Try using these commands to see what happens.

Comment: Now, if you double-click to edit a glyph, you can use File>Export in the glyph windows to export the selected glyph to, e.g., an SVG file, which you can use in Illustrator, or a PNG or BMP which you can use in Photoshop.